# UIView: How do i make the width automatically end before another image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

Right so i have this image: [image: shot]

And i need the width of the red bar to fit between the 2 images (Buttons) on all devices.

I have looked for answers but i haven't found anything that works yet.

This is the code I'm using:

```
_background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 353, 20)];
    [self addSubview:_background];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:_background];
    [_background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    _background.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    _background.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _background.center = CGPointMake(200, 15);
    _background.keepLeftOffsetTo(_sendButton);
    _background.keepCenterAlignTo(self);
    [_background updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

There may very well be an easy fix for this but I've only been on Objective-C for about a month! (Coming from Android Java).

Any help would be great right now

Thanks

Update #1: I've tried using Masonry as suggested but i still can't achieve what i need.

Comment: are you using storyboard? If so try using contraints and autolayout. Ctrl drag from your view to one button on the left and set margin and do the same for the right button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use Autolayout to achieve this.

If you are using storyboard to create the above layout, then you need to constraint the redView in between the buttons.

- Set the redView leading constraint to the firstImageView.
- Set the redViw trailing constraint to the last imageView.
- You need to give the height constraint to the redView.

Other constraints for the first and last imageviews:

- You need to give the top, height,width cosntraints to the first and last imageviews.

  If you are not using storyboard, I suggest to look into [MAsonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to apply constraints programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned that I'm not using storyboard, it's all setup programmatically. Is there any good ways of achieving the constraints without using MAsonry?

Comment: MAsonry gives you the easy way to setup constraints, if you want to set it up the original way, please look into NSLayoutConstraint.Setting constraints is what you need

Comment: I've tried using MAsonry but i still can't achieve it

Comment: I've marked this as correct as its what guided me to the solution. I have added the working code below!

Answer (score 1):

So to help i setup a quick storyboard and replicated what i needed, then i looked at the constraints from the storyboard and then replicated it programmatically. Like so:

```
[background mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker * make) {
    make.trailingMargin.equalTo(_sendButton);
    make.rightMargin.equalTo(@30);
    make.leading.equalTo(_optionsButton);
    make.leading.leadingMargin.equalTo(@25);
    make.height.equalTo(@20);
    make.center.equalTo(self);
        }];
```

As you can tell, i did end up using Masonry to do this.